# heading background 3 color in same row

Tags: html, css, background

```css
.heading {
    background-color: #FFC20E;
    font-size: 23px;
    font-weight: 600;
    padding: 5px 0px 5px 22px;
    font-family: "Open Sans";
}
```

```html
<h3 class="heading">Heading</h3>
```

I have a heading with 3 background color, how do I do please suggest, for reference I attached image, please help[image]

Comment: Add Some Code Here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use CSS gradient for this. To include a solid, non-transitioning color area within a gradient, include two positions for the color stop. Color stops can have two positions, which is equivalent to two consecutive color stops with the same color at different positions. [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Images/Using_CSS_gradients#creating_color_bands_stripes) for more information

```css
.heading{
padding:2px;
background: linear-gradient(to left,
      #fffb0e 25%, #ffe30e 25% 50%, #FFC20E 50% 100%);
}
```

```html
<h3 class="heading">Heading</h3>
```

Comment: @SandyS no worries, glad I could  help.

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS `gradient`

```css
.heading {
background: #fcc601; 
background: -moz-linear-gradient(left,  #fcc601 0%, #fcc601 46%, #ffdb71 46%, #ffdb71 73%, #fff0c5 73%, #fff0c5 100%);
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,  #fcc601 0%,#fcc601 46%,#ffdb71 46%,#ffdb71 73%,#fff0c5 73%,#fff0c5 100%);
background: linear-gradient(to right,  #fcc601 0%,#fcc601 46%,#ffdb71 46%,#ffdb71 73%,#fff0c5 73%,#fff0c5 100%);

    font-size: 23px;
    font-weight: 600;
    padding: 5px 0px 5px 22px;
    font-family: "Open Sans";
}
```

```html
<h3 class="heading">Heading</h3>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could define a CSS gradient with sharp colour boundaries for the background  as

> eg: background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, grey, grey 30%, white 30%, white);

But only a few browsers support that at the moment
See also http://www.webkit.org/blog/1424/css3-gradients/ for an explanation CSS3 gradients, including the sharp colour boundary trick.

```css
.heading {
    
    font-size: 23px;
    font-weight: 600;
    padding: 5px 0px 5px 22px;
    font-family: "Open Sans";
    background: linear-gradient(to right,
     #ffe30e 50%, #fffb0e 33% 80%, #FFFF8A 33% 100% );
}
```

```html
<h3 class="heading">Heading</h3>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `div` and inside that div, place three `span`s with a unique background to them and appropriate widths. Now, In the 1st span place your `h3` tag.
Here's the code,
HTML ->

```
                <div id="heading-div">
                    <span id="span1">
                        <h3>Heading</h3>
                    </span>
                    <span id="span2"></span>
                    <span id="span3"></span>
                </div>
```

CSS ->

```
                #heading-div{
                  display: flex;
                }
                #span1{
                  width: 50%;
                  background-color: #feab1e;
                }
                #span2{
                  width: 25%;
                  background-color: #ff8059;
                }
                #span3{
                  width: 25%;
                  background-color: #fff;
                }
```

Comment: If it's a fine answer you can add to his answer an upvote :)